# Apache virtual host both static and dynamic

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I want to configure my virtual host to use it for static files and dynamic scripts. I'm using Angular and Symfony2 , REST system at Symfony and front-end with Angular. But if I make http request into my API , I get an error No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', so I want to configure my virtual host working with static and dynamic and allow Angular make requests into API

Comment: so your rest host is another virtual host than your frontend host ?

Comment: They are in different folders. And  I want to make them in one host, one path that reads static files and works with API through angular.

Comment: a virtual host can only have one document root, why not have the rest and frontend part in the same symfony app ? maybe nelmio-cors bundle is easier than setting up acces-allow headers

Comment: I can create another bundle , but I don't completely understand how connect this two things.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jsonp on frontend or CORS on your backend to avoid this issue.
As jsonp seems to be hacky way I think you should try nelmio cors bundle it should fix your issues.